# JsonSerialization error using Alamofire in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i'm calling my signup service, in which parameters are going fine and url is also correct and i got status code 200 in response but when i print the result and response it shows Failure in it. I have checked everything that are required for signup everything looks fine but i'm confused why it is showing failure in response. It shows this in response,

```
["FirstName": "Awais", "Email": "awais@gmail.com", "PhoneNumber": "08965235415", "Password": "123456", "LastName": "Ahmed", "ConfirmPassword": "123456"]
Request: Optional(MyURL)
Response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x604000438900> { URL: http://api.theahsanzaman.info/api/Account/Register } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Cache-Control" =     (
    "no-cache"
);
"Content-Length" =     (
    0
);
Date =     (
    "Tue, 17 Apr 2018 13:37:03 GMT"
);
Expires =     (
    "-1"
);
Pragma =     (
    "no-cache"
);
Server =     (
    "Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
);
"X-AspNet-Version" =     (
    "4.0.30319"
);
"X-Powered-By" =     (
    "ASP.NET"
);
"X-Powered-By-Plesk" =     (
    PleskWin
);
} })  


Result: FAILURE
RR FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)
0

1111
"FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)"
```

My code for the request is this,

```
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import UIKit

class SignUpService{

    static let instance = SignUpService()
    var status = 0

    func signUpUser(param:[String: String],completion:@escaping CompletionHandler)  {

        let url = URL.init(string: SignUpUrl)
        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            print("Result: \(response.result)")// response serialization result
            print("RR \(response)")

            if response.result.error == nil{
                self.status = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                if(self.status == 200){
                    print("successful")

                }
                completion(true)
                print("11112222")
            }else{
                completion(false)
                print("1111")
                debugPrint(response.description as Any)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused why it isn't showing success in response if status code is 200.

Comment: There are many different kind of errors. Status 200 means that the error is **not** related to the network request. But `inputDataNilOrZeroLength` is pretty meaningful.

Comment: `"Content-Length" = (0)`. You have no data, and JSONSerialization might causes an error then and throw that error `inputDataNilOrZeroLength`. Maybe check beforehand the status code instead?

Comment: i got that it was due to responseJSON it should be converted to responseString.

Answer (score 0):

> Validate the response status code while calling API by adding validate(statusCode: 200..<299) on alamofire request.

**Now your code will fall in success if success code is 200.**

```
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil). validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data): 
            Logs.DLog(object: "\n Success: \(response)")

            // Do your code here...

        case .failure(let error):
            Logs.DLog(object: "\n Failure: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            // Do your code here...

        }
    })
```

But you are not getting response JSON so you can not decode response JSON.